# Roadmap for <amp-story>

Tags: amp-html

I understand that `<amp-story>` is currently in experimental. May I know where I can find out more about the roadmap of `<amp-story>`, especially when it will become General Available.

I have check out https://www.ampproject.org/roadmap/ but it doesn't seem to mention anything on it.

Comment: The roadmap linked is outdated (from Q4 2017); there was a little bit of `amp-story` roadmap information given at the end of the [Telling Stories with AMP talk](https://youtu.be/aael0hECWFw) at AMP Conf 2018.  While the component is still experimental, new features are released on a weekly basis, and the component is already available for use.  If you let me know what you were hoping to gain from general availability that is not already possible today, I can shed light on the availability of your specific concerns, irrespective of any "general availability" date.

Comment: I understand that it is still actively being developed and released on weekly basis. As a average developer, I need to know when it is "stable" enough for general development for public consumption without being behind the "Origin Trials" whitelist.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-story) has just been updated to begin referring to the 1.0 version, and the component will be moving out from behind the origin trials whitelist in the next 1-2 weeks.  The component is still marked as experimental, but there will be no whitelist process or known breaking changes.

Comment: @JonNewmuis Thanks for the updated info and insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A roadmap for the `<amp-story>` component has been made available at https://www.ampproject.org/roadmap/amp-story.

Comment: Any idea when amp-story will be graduated from `experimental`?